# Assassin's Creed 3: The Tyranny of King Washington DLCs total Length

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Do you know the approximate length of time to complete all Assassin's creed 3 Single Player DLCs? As I know there are four Washington DLC. Could someone please confirm?

Comment: I have amended your post in order to make it more literate.

Comment: All the DLCs haven't been released yet. So far only the first two have been released with the third coming soon (hopefully). Your question is unanswerable. With that said, each of the DLCs so far should take about an hour of gameplay to complete.

Comment: @JeffMercado Ok. Thanks. So we can say  it gonna take about 5 hours approximately.

Comment: @kotekzot Are you kidding? I have already seacrhed AC3: DLCs in HowLongToBeat and found nothing. SO?????

Comment: That question and its answers are provided as a courtesy, Arqade doesn't do game length questions.

Comment: @kotekzot Ok. I Understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each DLC should take around, approximately - 1 hour to 1 1/2 hours to complete. As there are going to be more DLC releases in the not too distant future, it's hard to determine how many will actually be released.

Comment: FYI: There will only be three, as far as the Tyranny of King Washington is concerned.